# Python - single vs multiline REGEX

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, multiline

Considering the following text pattern,

#goals: the process report timestamp, eg. **2011-09-21 15:45:00** and the first two stats in succ. statistics line, eg:   **1438     1439**

```
input_text = '''
# Process_Name     ( 23387) Report at 2011-09-21 15:45:00.001    Type:  Periodic    #\n
some line 1\n
some line 2\n
some other lines\n
succ. statistics |     1438     1439  99 |   3782245    3797376  99 |\n
some lines\n
Process_Name     ( 23387) Report at 2011-09-21 15:50:00.001    Type:  Periodic    #\n
some line 1\n
some line 2\n
some other lines\n
succ. statistics |     1436     1440  99 |   3782459    3797523  99 |\n
repeat the pattern several hundred times...
'''
```

I got it working when iterating line to line,

```
def parse_file(file_handler, patterns):

    results = []
    for line in file_handler:
        for key in patterns.iterkeys():
            result = re.match(patterns[key], line)
            if result:
                results.append( result )

return results

patterns = {
    'report_date_time': re.compile('^# Process_Name\s*\(\s*\d+\) Report at (.*)\.[0-9]   {3}\s+Type:\s*Periodic\s*#\s*.*$'),
    'serv_term_stats': re.compile('^succ. statistics \|\s+(\d+)\s+   (\d+)+\s+\d+\s+\|\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\|\s*$'),
    }
results = parse_file(fh, patterns)
```

returning

```
[('2011-09-21 15:40:00',),
('1425', '1428'),
('2011-09-21 15:45:00',),
('1438', '1439')]
```

but having a list of tuples output as my goal,

```
[('2011-09-21 15:40:00','1425', '1428'),
('2011-09-21 15:45:00', '1438', '1439')]
```

I tried several combos with the initial patterns and a lazy quantifier between them but can't figure out how to capture the patterns using a multiline REGEX

```
# .+?   Lazy quantifier "match as few characters as possible (all characters allowed) until reaching the next expression"
pattern = '# Process_Name\s*\(\s*\d+\) Report at (.*)\.[0-9]{3}\s+Type:\s*Periodic.*?succ. statistics) \|\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)+\s+\d+\s+\|\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\|\s'
regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.MULTILINE)

data = file_handler.read()    
for match in regex.finditer(data):
    results = match.groups()
```

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but why are you embedding \n in a multi-line string like that? The actual newlines in the string are newlines.

Comment: Right Wooble, this is in Linux so just added them to express the newline character (trying to avoid the usual is it \n or \r or \r\n ?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `re.DOTALL` so `.` will match any character, including newlines:

```
import re

data = '''
# Process_Name     ( 23387) Report at 2011-09-21 15:45:00.001    Type:  Periodic    #\n
some line 1\n
some line 2\n
some other lines\n
succ. statistics |     1438     1439  99 |   3782245    3797376  99 |\n
some lines\n
repeat the pattern several hundred times...
'''

pattern = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*?succ. statistics\s+\|\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)'
regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

for match in regex.finditer(data):
    results = match.groups()
    print(results)

    # ('2011-09-21', '1438', '1439')
```

Comment: Wow. You're fast. Thanks for the answer and the improvements unutbu, and thanks stackoverflow for gurus like you!

Comment: Edit: A minor bump, I do need to garantee a non greedy quantifier, else that regex would only capture the first timestamp, the last stats, ignoring the thousand+ lines in between. Thus, pattern = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*?succ. statistics\s+\|\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)'